# Using POS-tagged string with ANTLR

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp, antlr4

I have a string which I am tagging using Stanford CoreNLP POS Tagger. Now, I want the words in the string to act like values (terminals) and the corresponding tag of each word to act as the token (non-terminal).

For example if the tagged string is:

`Three/CD, critics/NNS, review/VBP, a/DT, book/NN, ./.`

Then, I want these tags (CD, NNS, VBP, etc.) to be passed to ANTLR 4 parser as token stream with the words in the sentence (Three, critics, review, etc.) being values of these tokens which can be inferred later.

I want to ask if there is an efficient way I can parse the sentence using ANTLR but use my own methods to supply the tokens?

PS: I am using ANTLR 4 IDE plugin for Eclipse. No tag for it yet!

Answer (score 0):

Extend `CommonToken` to create your own custom token with methods and fields appropriate for the tagging. Extend `CommonTokenFactory` to supply your tokens to the lexer when called; use `Lexer.setTokenFactory()` to make the factory available.